# Change size of text based on number of words - android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was using a library to help auto fit text into a button, however even though it worked for three android phones, for a bigger android phone, some text randomly shrunk in size even though they didn't need to. Example in screenshot show:[image]

So instead I had a thought. I will set the xml as a normal button like so:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btnans4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/blue"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Answer - 4"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

Buttons 1, 2 and 3 have same xml as above but different id and text.

What I am thinking is using dynamic text size. So I will remove the textSize 15sp from the xml above and instead I want to do the following:

- If the button contains more than 5 words, the text size for that button = 12sp, else it's 15sp.

How can this be achieved?

```
Button btnans1, btnans2, btnans3, btnans4;

       btnans1 = findViewById(R.id.btnans1);
        btnans2 = findViewById(R.id.btnans2);
        btnans3 = findViewById(R.id.btnans3);
        btnans4 = findViewById(R.id.btnans4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First put these lines in `dimens.xml` in `res/values` folder, to define the 2 desired text sizes:

```
<dimen name="btn_text_size_small">12sp</dimen>
<dimen name="btn_text_size_normal">15sp</dimen>
```

Next use this code to apply the text sizes:

```
    Button[] buttons = {btnans1, btnans2, btnans3, btnans4};

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        String text = buttons[i].getText().toString().trim();

        String[] words = text.split(" ");

        Float size;

        if (words.length > 5) {
            size = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.btn_text_size_small);
        } else {
            size = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.btn_text_size_normal);
        }

        buttons[i].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
    }
```

I hope i don't have typos.

Comment: Just testing it now

Comment: @mmkp I hope you test my last code, because I did have typos

Comment: Saw your edit, this is the one I am pasting now and I will update you in 2 min

Comment: It counts the words by he number of spaces

Comment: Just setting the text to be smaller to make sure but it doesn't seem to change text size for the long answers

Comment: Long are considered the answers with > 5 words

Comment: Make sure in dimensions you use `sp` and not `dp`

Comment: Yes anything longer than 5 words. Just tested again and it is deffo not changing font size for long answers. I have an answer that goes 'The Masters, U.S Open, The Open and U.S. PGA Championships' and it is still displaying in 15sp font and not 12sp based on the dimen

Comment: There is no text size set in the xml for the button just in case you was going to ask that, I made sure that was removed

Comment: I just tested the text 'The Masters, U.S Open, The Open and U.S. PGA Championships' and it works fine

Comment: For this code to work the buttons must have text. If the text changes the code must be executed again.

Comment: Yeah I noticed in the java that there was default code for text size 15 as well. I tried again and noticed something perculier and I think it's because of were I placed your code. Basically, I get a answer that has more than 5 words and text isn't set to 12dp. However in next question, the aer that has taken the place of that button then displays in 12dp

Comment: So I am going to move the code into the create rather than what I thought the questionLoad() method and test again

Comment: You must put the code right after the code that gives the text to the buttons

Comment: If it doesn't work then I may just have to send yo a google drive link of the code and ask for assitsance in where to place it. I am actually not a dev but a freelance dev made this and I noticed a bug (as I am a tester) and wanted to sort this bug out

Comment: Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K3mrJHMRp_miOSv3HhRwx1IgUtLy_qkw/view?usp=sharing - I have placed the code in the middle (just do a find) but I must be putting it in the wrong place

Comment: In `onCreate()` just after `QuestionLoad();`

Comment: I'm sure I put it there to begin with and did not do it but i will test again to make sure

Comment: It is deffo not doing it

Comment: Put it inside QuestionLoad() right after all the btnans1.setText(Html.fromHtml(ans1));....

Comment: Sorry fell asleep as it wad 1a, back in my place. I will give it a go